# Microsoft Emotion API using requests Error 400

Tags: python, azure

I am using Microsoft Emotion API using python + requests

Using the following code I am always getting a 400 error -

> "Indicates JSON parsing error, faceRectangles cannot be parsed correctly, or count exceeds 64, or content-type is not recognized."

```
import requests
n = int(raw_input())
url = "https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/emotion/v1.0/recognize"
headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json", "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"}
while n>0:
    str = raw_input()
    body = '''{ "url": "''' + str + '''" }'''
    r = requests.post(url, data = body,headers = headers)
    print(r.status_code)
    if r.status_code == 200:    
        print(r.content)
    n = n-1
```

and the input

```
1
http://i.imgur.com/ytsbJBy.jpg
```

Comment: @peter-pan-msft

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce your issue, but failed because your code works fine on my environment. The `requests` version on my local is `2.13.0`. Please manually call Emotion API via `Postman` to make sure the issue which was not caused by Azure Cognitive Service, and check the `requests` version whether be old via command `pip freeze`.

Meanwhile, I suggest to rewrite the code `body = '''{ "url": "''' + str + '''" }'''` like below for more humanable.

```
body = "{'url': '%s'}" % str
```

or

```
body = "{{'url': '{0}'}}".format(str)
```

Any concern or update, please feel free to let me know.